# Check if file exists

Tags: rss

I have a simple [rss feed](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/rss-feed) in my Templates directory, appropriately named "feed.rss". I'm trying to create a link to that file but I don't want that to show up if the file doesn't exist. How might be the best way to only show the link, if the file exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do with out-of-the-box Twig/Craft, but it's a super-easy [plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction) to write.

All you'd need is to give your plugin a [Template Variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/variables) so that you could do:

```
{% if craft.myAwesomePlugin.fileExists('somePath') %}
    YES
{% endif %}
```

And your `MyAwesomePluginVariable` class has a method like:

```
public function fileExists($path)
{
    return IOHelper::fileExists($path);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brad, this is a nice clean solution that works well. However, it only checks files that are in the Public directory, and not the Template directory. Going to see if any of the include file functions will be of use. Thanks again.